# How to receive real time notifications in Angular frontend from Spring kafka backend

Tags: angular, spring, apache-kafka, notifications, real-time-data

I am wondering if it is possible to send real time user notifications to an angular client from spring kafka backend, my approach was to send it through the kafka topics instead of using websocket STOMP, and create a topic for each user, and in someway the angular subscribes to the current logged in user topic and listen to their notifications, I tried to look for a kafka client library for the angular client but I didn't find anything useful, my best shot was a library that is 10 years old and I honestly don't trust an out of date library to do the job.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kafka isn't a frontend technology such that a client side JS library exists, and doesn't push events.

You can make your kafka consumer application do anything you want, such as send GCM/APNS messages, or forward data to some other system that is responsible for sending such notifications. But "one topic per user" is generally an anti pattern with Kafka since the brokers do have a limit on number of topics they support, but your userbase might grow indefinitely.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I was thinking that the topic per user is not going to be efficient as the database grows.. I mean can you please suggest a better approach.. and about the client side.. I wonder if using a websocket would solve the problem and could the websocket subscribes to the kafka topic or should i add websocket configuration to my backend

Comment: As mentioned, Kafka isn't a frontend technology. It doesn't offer websockets out of the box

Comment: yes true, I could finally do that in with SSE since notifications are one way communication, wasn't really necessary for us to integrate websockets since we only needed one way real time communication.. thank you both for the explanation